# why onReceive() is being called many times?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i do not know why when i connect or disconnect the wifi, the corresponding callback in the below posted code of the wifi receiver, is called many times at least three times, and

therefore, if i want to call a function based on the current wifi state, that function will be called many times and i do not want such behaviour, especially that, in the

function that should be called when there is wifi connection, i am displaying a dialog, and being that callback will be called many times, the dialog will be
called many times and it will cause overlap.

please have alok at the below posted logcat, it is just an example o what i am getting.

please let me know why the corresponding callback of the wifi status is getting called many times, and how to avoid such multiple calling?

**code**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    tv_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);

    this.registerReceiver(this.myWifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
}

private BroadcastReceiver myWifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "@onReceive()");

        mConnMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(network_service);
        WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(WiFi_Service);

        switch (wifiMgr.getWifiState()) {
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
            Log.d(TAG, "wifi enabled");

            if (mConnMgr != null) {
                networkInfo = mConnMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (networkInfo != null) {
                    switch(networkInfo.getType()) {
                    case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI: 
                        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                            tv_status.setText("Connected");
                            Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
                        }else if (networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                            tv_status.setText("Status: CONNECTED Or CONNECTING");
                            Log.d(TAG, "Status: CONNECTED Or CONNECTING");
                        }else if (networkInfo.isFailover()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "Status: FailOver");
                        }else if (networkInfo.isRoaming()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Status: Roaming");
                        }else if (networkInfo.isAvailable()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Status: Available");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Status: disconnected");
                        }
                        break;

                    }
                }else {
                    tv_status.setText("Status: No Default NetWork Connected");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status: No Default NetWork Connected");
                }
            } else {
                tv_status.setText("Status:  ConnMgr is null");
                Log.d(TAG, "Status:  ConnMgr is null");
            }

            break;
```

**LogCat**:

```
03-04 15:31:31.031: D/MainActivity(16120): @onReceive()
03-04 15:31:31.031: D/MainActivity(16120): wifi enabled
03-04 15:31:31.032: D/MainActivity(16120): Status: No Default NetWork Connected
03-04 15:31:31.546: D/MainActivity(16120): @onReceive()
03-04 15:31:31.547: D/MainActivity(16120): wifi enabled
03-04 15:31:31.547: D/MainActivity(16120): Status: No Default NetWork Connected
03-04 15:31:31.617: D/MainActivity(16120): @onReceive()
03-04 15:31:31.618: D/MainActivity(16120): wifi enabled
03-04 15:31:31.620: D/MainActivity(16120): Status: No Default NetWork Connected
03-04 15:31:31.636: D/MainActivity(16120): @onReceive()
03-04 15:31:31.636: D/MainActivity(16120): wifi enabled
03-04 15:31:31.637: D/MainActivity(16120): Status: No Default NetWork Connected
03-04 15:32:28.661: D/MainActivity(16120): @onReceive()
03-04 15:32:28.663: D/MainActivity(16120): wifi enabled
03-04 15:32:28.666: D/MainActivity(16120): Status: No Default NetWork Connected
03-04 15:32:28.708: D/MainActivity(16120): @onReceive()
03-04 15:32:28.709: D/MainActivity(16120): wifi enabled
03-04 15:32:28.710: D/MainActivity(16120): Status: No Default NetWork Connected
03-04 15:32:28.722: D/MainActivity(16120): @onReceive()
03-04 15:32:28.722: D/MainActivity(16120): wifi enabled
03-04 15:32:28.722: D/MainActivity(16120): Status: No Default NetWork Connected
```

**Update_1**:

**MySolution using a Timer**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    tv_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
    IntentFilter intfil = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    this.registerReceiver(this.myWifiReceiver, intfil);
}

private BroadcastReceiver myWifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "@onReceive()");
        Timer t1 = new Timer();
        Timer t2 = new Timer();

        if (!locked) {
            if (scheduled1) {
                t1.cancel();
                t1.purge();
            }
            if (scheduled2) {
                t2.cancel();
                t2.purge();
            }

            WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(WiFi_Service);

            switch (wifiMgr.getWifiState()) {
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
                Log.d(TAG, "wifi enabled");
                locked = true;
                t1 = new Timer();
                t1.schedule(MQTTReceiverLockTimedTask, 4000);
                scheduled1 = true;
                module();
                break;

            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
                Log.d(TAG, "wifi disabled");
                locked = true;
                t2 = new Timer();
                t2.schedule(MQTTReceiverLockTimedTask, 4000);
                scheduled2 = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

TimerTask MQTTReceiverLockTimedTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        locked = false;
    }
};

protected void module() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mConnMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(network_service);

    if (mConnMgr != null) {
        networkInfo = mConnMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            switch(networkInfo.getType()) {
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI: 
                if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    tv_status.setText("Connected");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
                }else if (networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                    tv_status.setText("Status: CONNECTED Or CONNECTING");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status: CONNECTED Or CONNECTING");
                }else if (networkInfo.isFailover()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status: FailOver");
                }else if (networkInfo.isRoaming()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status: Roaming");
                }else if (networkInfo.isAvailable()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status: Available");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Status: disconnected");
                }
                break;

            }
        }else {
            tv_status.setText("Status: No Default NetWork Connected");
            Log.d(TAG, "Status: No Default NetWork Connected");
        }
    } else {
        tv_status.setText("Status:  ConnMgr is null");
        Log.d(TAG, "Status:  ConnMgr is null");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code from where are you calling this receiver?

Comment: @Apurva please see it above, i posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [WifiManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) on
`WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`:

> Broadcast intent action indicating that the state of establishing a connection to an access point has changed.One extra provides the new SupplicantState.

You are getting many calls to `onReceive()`because `SupplicantState` provides a more detailed information on the state of the establishing connection. Every time this state changes, a new intent is broadcast. Since you only need a less detailed information from this, it seems that you are getting same broadcasts many times.

As on how to avoid this: either search for another intent to listen, such as `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` if it suits your needs, or try Mahmoud Elmorabea's solution - save the current wifi connection state in a private field on your Activity class, and on the `onReceive()`, check if the connection state has changed. If it has not, skip the rest of the code. Otherwise, run the code and update your status. If you use this solution, remember to save the state field during the Activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the current state of the WiFi somewhere, a manager or something, and only execute your code if the onReceive() is invoked with different state than the current one.

Let us say you are using this code in an Activity.

In you activity you will have a property called currentWifiState and at first it is equal to -100; for example

and in your receiver the code goes like this

```
if (wifiManager.getWifiState() == currentWifiState)
     return;
```

Then if the state you are being notified with is the same as the current one, you will do nothing.

Your code will not be executed unless the Wifi state changes.

Comment: would you please elaborate and clarify further? sorry i did nt get your point

Comment: but why there are multiple calls ?? any answer!!

Comment: Maybe other things have changed about the connection or the wifi adapter, but the value you are interested in stays the same, i am not sure though.

Comment: ok, i tried to solve thuis issue using a timer, shoule i post the code? maybe u can advise

Comment: I don't think a timer is the best solution, have you tried the solution above?, but sure post what u tried, maybe i can help

Comment: i posted the code with timer above, in the update_1 section....regarding ur soution , i am still trying to understand it :)